# How to redirect user to the developer iTunes account to see his other apps

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

I am trying to implement a "More apps" button that redirects to the other apps that the same developer have posted on iTunes app store, for example to achieve what I am trying to do with the Temple Run developer the next code is just fine:

```
NSString* launchUrl = @"https://itunes.apple.com/ro/artist/imangi-studios-llc/id284899742";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```

The think is, that in my case the developer has no other app posted on iTunes yet so I can not search iTunes and right click to copy the developers link...

So my question is the next one:
How can I get the next two information that compose the final link:

1-imangi-studios-llc

2-id284899742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Company / organisation name, could be find using [apple membercenter](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#profile). The url part is probably composed by replacing empty space with "-" and making string lowercase, eg: *Imangi Studios LLC* becomes *imangi-studios-llc*
2. After you add your app at [iTunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), you will be able to see id. Just open newly created app in iTunes connect and check url. It will look like this https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/**284899742** and id will be **id284899742**

Comment: regarding the first part, so my company/ organization is listed in the Apple ID and Primary Email Address witch are the same is the created account is a simple developer account (99$) ?

Comment: regarding the second part the id that you suggest I think it is specific to each app, it is no  the developer id

Comment: apparently the id number is called D-U-N-S Number

Comment: the id in answer is given as example, and will be different for all apps

Comment: I am just curious if I am doing it wright, so in some cases the id can be the actual email address

Comment: where can I find it, because the developer account has no apps posted yet, these will be the first one

Comment: first you need to create app (not submit) in iTunes connect, see my answer

Comment: i managed to find out the account name like:Imangi Studios LLC but I think that the id you suggested is valid only for this app