# IOS + Swift, How to redirect to iTunes purchase page

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, itunes-store

I'm making an app that we could play preview and purchase song from iTunes. Let's say I have song title named "Test Song" on "First" album from artist named "John". What I need to do is, when I tap button "Buy This Song On iTunes" it open iTunes and directly go to song page where we can purchase this song, how can I do that?

I've seen this method on app called Shazam.

Comment: Hi this is may be useful for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921211/how-to-redirect-user-to-the-developer-itunes-account-to-see-his-other-app

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way would be get the trackViewUrl of your song from iTunes Search API, and then direct user to the url. For example, you can get the trackViewUrl for the song 'Something Just Like This' from the response return by iTunes Search API as below.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/something-just-like-this/id1207120422?i=1207120448&uo=4
```

And what you should really do is to do the following

```
let trackViewUrl   = "YOUR TRACK VIEW URL"
let affiliateToken = "YOUR AFFILIATE TOKEN"
guard let url = URL(string: trackViewUrl + "&at=\(affiliateToken)&app=itunes") else {
        //handle error here
        return
    }
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

Tips:

- Remember to insert your affiliate token, otherwise you won't receive credits.
- Remember to set app=itunes, otherwise it will open the url in Music App.