# Is there still a way to open an iTunes search API trackViewUrl in iTunes Store and not Apple Music?

Tags: ios, itunes-store, apple-music, itunes-search-api

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223732/ios-swift-how-to-redirect-to-itunes-purchase-page) we can get a JSON response from the iTunes Search API to direct users to the `trackViewUrl`. The answer suggested appending `&app=itunes` to have the iOS device open the URL in the iTunes Store instead of Apple Music, but my test suggests that this doesn't work and Apple Music is still opened.

For instance, the first item of the result of:

[https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=pink+floyd%20high%20hopes](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=pink%20floyd%20high%20hopes)

shows a `trackViewUrl` of:

https://music.apple.com/us/album/high-hopes/1067444712?i=1067444898&uo=4,

with the appended request is:

https://music.apple.com/us/album/high-hopes/1067444712?i=1067444898&uo=4&app=itunes

However, this link opens Apple Music on an iOS device.

Is there a way to open the iTunes Store instead? Or another way to open the iTunes Store to a specific track? I need DRM free tracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing this now is with [StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/offering_media_for_sale_in_your_app).

Comment: I don't undestand your answer but it is marked as best answer. Can you develop your purpose? You want to say he should use Store Kit for make in app purchase at least redirect user to iTunes Store ? But he can't do this because he has not the product